# Coverting a function with functions as parameters

Tags: scala

I have a few functions with the same code partner as the following

```
def updateFoo(fooId: Long, user: String): Option[Foo] = {

  val fooMaybe = fooDao.getById(fooId)
  fooMaybe match {
    case Some(foo) =>
      fooDao.update(
        foo.copy(updatedBy = Some(user), validationStatus = Some(ValidationStatus.Valid))
      )
    case None =>
      throw new Exception(s"Foo with ID: '$fooId' doesn't exist")
  }
}
```

where Foo is a case class.

To reduce duplicated code, I write the following function aiming to be shared by other functions

```
  private def doIt(f1: Long => Option[Object],  parameter1: Long, f2: Object => Option[Object], paramter2: String ): Option[Object] ={

val somethingMaybe = f1(parameter1)
somethingMaybe match {
  case Some(something) =>
    f2(
      something.copy(updatedBy = Some(paramter2),
        validationStatus = Some(ValidationStatus.Valid)) // <-- can't be complied 
    )
  case None =>
    throw new DomainException(s"Object with ID: '$parameter1' doesn't exist")
 }
}
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

You stated `f2` function only accept one parameter:

```
f2: Object => Option[Object]
```

but you invoke this function with two parameters:

```
f2(
  something.copy(updatedBy = Some(paramter2),
  validationStatus = Some(ValidationStatus.Valid) // <-- can't be complied 
)
```

Maybe you want to change you `f2` statement like:

```
f2: (Object, Option[ValidationStatus]) => Option[Object]
```

Comment: I missed a close bracket there. I have a correction.